# program variable values during execution

Tags: c

Is there a way to get the value of all variables in c during each execution step of a program.

Some other method except GDB.

Thanks in advance
-Sahil

Comment: printf is your friend

Comment: yes there are lots of ways

Comment: What's wrong with GDB ??

Comment: Are you saying that you cannot recompile with debug statements or with the gdb link active? Please explain the problem in more detail.

Comment: @Vorsprung-plz elaborate

Comment: @sabbahillel-- there was a command i am forgetting which usually gives a blueprint of the whole program.

Answer (score 1):

The debug statements you are talking about are the `printf`s **marcadian** pointed out, which you will have to do manually, I don't know any other way in which you can tell the compiler to build the executable such that it will automatically print the variables except from **GDB**. All you have to do is compile the file like this : `gcc -g file.c -o output.o`. The `-g` flag constructs the table for gdb, have a look at some tutorials online http://www.cprogramming.com/gdbtutorial.html on how to use it afterwards.

Edit: `info locals` will be quite useful to print all the local ones